# Batch file if condition for testing Saturday and Sunday

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I have this code:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('powershell ^(get-date^).DayOfWeek') do set dow=%%i
echo %dow%
if NOT %dow% == "Saturday" if NOT %dow% == "Sunday" 
(
    start "" "D:\Program Files (2012)\Openfire\bin\openfire.exe"
)
```

Basically I want if it is Saturday or Sunday then it should not start the program but for all other days it should start the program. Today is Saturday and yet the program starts. In `%dow%` I correctly get Saturday but still it executes the start command. What am I missing?

Comment: doublequotes are included in the comparison - therefor `%dow%` NEQ `"Saturday"`. The conditional statements should read: `If not "%dow%" == "Dayname" command`

Comment: …and there is a superfluous line-break before the opening parenthesis…

Comment: It is a bit curious for me to use a batch file interpreted by `cmd.exe` which uses its dedicated successor `powershell.exe` to get day of week. Why not using a pure [Windows commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) solution? I suggest as second line `set dow=7` and as third line `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH  Win32_LocalTime GET DayOfWeek /Value') do set /A dow=%%I` and as last line `if not %dow% == 6 if not %dow% == 0 start "" "D:\Program Files (2012)\Openfire\bin\openfire.exe"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of using a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) for this:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile ^
 "If ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -NotMatch \"Sunday^|Saturday\") { Exit 2 }"
@If ErrorLevel 2 Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Openfire\bin\openfire.exe"
```

Or do it the opposite way:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile ^
 "If ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -Match \"Sunday^|Saturday\") { Exit 2 }"
@If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B
@Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Openfire\bin\openfire.exe"
```

Note that I have assumed that your submitted code was unnecessarily changing the location of the openfire executable, so have replaced `D:\Program Files (2012)` with a built in variable for the most likely location, at `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

*Just be aware that `Sunday` and `Saturday` are localized strings.*